# how can install vue js in laravel 8 without any error when setup Laravel 8 and Vue Js page vue template not displaying

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I installed a fresh Laravel 8 and Vue-js. upon installing the npm and vue it installs well. Now my problem is when I run the npm run watch then load the page it is a blank white page

step install is

composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app

cd example-app

php artisan serve

composer require laravel/breeze --dev

php artisan breeze:install

npm install

npm run dev

php artisan migrate

my testapp.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello world! asasasaas</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

my views/testpage.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
       <main-app></main-app>
    </div>
</body>
 <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

my js/app.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('main-app', require('./components/TestApp.vue').default);


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

my webpack.mix.js

```
    const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */



mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
       // require('postcss-import'),
      //  require('tailwindcss'),
      //  require('autoprefixer'),
    ])
    .vue();
```

route in web.php

```
Route::get('/test', [TestController::class, 'index']);
```

Can someone help me figured this thing out? when I load the page it is a blank white page. it seems the vue is not loaded.

Comment: Did you install it via `laravel/ui`?

Comment: laravel/breeze installing

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/ui has a "preset" for Laravel/Vue, might want to try this. Before that you could try to change your route to `[App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class, 'index']`, L8 changed the way to use Controllers in routes a little. Do other pages (without Vue) work? Nothing in your browsers console? Or Laravel's log?

Comment: thx  but not work with breeze ?

Comment: breeze is an upgrade version of Laravel UI, don't use Laravel UI anymore.

Comment: also your app.js looks like Vue 2 where breeze would install Vue 3 and app.js would look differently,

Comment: how install vue 3 in laravel